# WebDeploy: Change Package Output folder in Web Publishing Pipeline

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have a Visual Studio solution with multiple webapp projects. The build should create a web package for each project. The web packages should finally end up in a folder structor like this:

```
$(Outputfolder)
|
+-- Web
    |
    +-- <name package 1>
    |   |
    |   +-- ... package files ...
    |
    +-- <name package 2>
    |   |
    |   +-- ... package files ...
    |
    +-- ...
    |
```

In order to change the destination folder for a web package I have added a .wpp.targets file to each web app project. Here I have adjusted the DefaultPackageOutputDir property:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefaultPackageOutputDir Condition=" '$(DefaultPackageOutputDir)'=='' ">$(OutFolder)Web\Webapp1\</DefaultPackageOutputDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

This is it how I call MSBuild. I simply hand over the output folder as a property:

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(ItemToBuild)"
         Targets="Build"
         Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);
                     Platform=$(Platform);
                     DeployOnBuild=True;
                     DeployTarget=Package;
                     OutFolder=$(OutFolder)" />
```

This does the trick but I'm not completely satisfied. I want to make the build more general. It bothers me, that I have to name the webapp explicitly. My idea was to use the property DefaultMSDeployDestinationApplicationName instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <DefaultPackageOutputDir Condition=" '$(DefaultPackageOutputDir)'=='' ">$(OutFolder)Web\$(DefaultMSDeployDestinationApplicationName)\</DefaultPackageOutputDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Unfortunately the property DefaultMSDeployDestinationApplicationName seems to be empty. The package files end up in the Web folder. I guess the property DefaultMSDeployDestinationApplicationName is not yet defined at the time the .wpp.targets file is readed.

Does somebody know a better place to define the property DefaultPackageOutputDir?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, I was not able to solve this. At last I have switched to FAKE.

Comment: I got it-- see below.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change the output directory for a Web Project by specifying the following options to MsBuild:

```
/p:OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\$(BuildConfiguration)" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
```